# Is it possible to move resource allocating objects to a different scope without using pointers while it is also efficient?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have an Object which allocates a resource in its constr., and releases it in its destr.

I want to store these Objects in a diffrent scope.

If I pass the Object in a function the default copy constr. only copies values, and the allocated resource will be released at the end of the original scope.

If I override the copy constr. to allocate the resource, it's code duplication, and allocates the resource twice.

Is it possible to move resource allocating objects to a different scope without using pointers while it is also efficient?

Comment: Use move constructor or move assignment.

Comment: Without using ANY pointer, no. Even std::vectors are using pointers in implementation. Otherwise they would be scoped closed.

Comment: You can pass your objects by reference (or const reference if needed).

Comment: "allocates a resource in its constr., and releases it in its destr" - this implies pointers of some kind (or otherwise a container type, which presumably supports move semantics). Why the "without using pointers" restriction then?